# How to define a @findBy annotation in a subclass, using PageFactory?

Tags: c#, selenium, findby, page-factory

I work in an automation project with Selenium and C #.
I use the Page Object pattern to define each of the pages (with their locators), and then define the tests separately in a Test class.
I have a Page class that is the base class of the pages, where I call:
PageFactory.InitElements (webDriver, this);

and define the common methods for all the pages.
Then each page inherits from Page, and the corresponding elements are defined using @FindBy annotations:

```
[FindsBy (How = How.Id, Using = "UserName")]
public IWebElement UserName {get; set; }

[FindsBy(How = How.Id, Using = "UserPass")]
public IWebElement Password { get; set; }

[FindsBy(How = How.Id, Using = "login-btn")]
public IWebElement SubmitButton { get; set; }
```

A new login page was added, and I have to keep both (new and old login) and be able to run the tests with both pages.
Both pages have the **same elements (not the locators)**, and they must be able to **respond to the same methods** such as: login (user, pass)
The idea would be to define a hierarchy of classes: BaseLogin (inherited from Page), LoginPage and NewLoginPage (both inherit from BaseLogin), where in BaseLogin you can define the elements (IWebElement) and the common methods.
Then in each subclass associate / relate each element with the corresponding locator.

**This is to avoid repeating the code that allows me to interact with the page, on each of the pages.**

```
public class BaseLoginPage : Page
{
 protected IWebElement UserName { get; set; }
 protected IWebElement Password { get; set; }
 protected IWebElement SubmitButton { get; set; }
}
    // BaseLogin just define the IWebElement without assign a specific locator.
```

**How can I associate/relate the element "IWebElement UserName" with its corresponding locator?**

```
[FindsBy(How = How.Id, Using = "UserName")]   --> in LoginPage Class
[FindsBy(How = How.Id, Using = "user")]       --> in NewLoginPage Class
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about using an or operator? If the login is the same for both, this would just send the value to whichever locator is on the page.

```
 [FindsBy(How = How.Id, Using = "user | UserName")]
```

or XPath

```
 [FindsBy(How = How.XPath, Using = "//input[@id='user'] | //input[@id='UserName']")]
```

Comment: Thanks @Dazed for your replied. I think it could solve my problem, but following your approach, how can I do when the same IWebElement is refered by ID in one page, and by CssSselector un the other? Exampe:  `[FindsBy(How = How.CssSelector, Using = ".dp-button")]  public IWebElement SubmitButton [FindsBy(How = How.Id, Using = "login-btn")]  public IWebElement SubmitButton`

Comment: Could it be something like that?
[FindsBy(How = How.CssSelector | How.Id, Using = ".dp-button | login-btn")]

I really appreciate if someone can help me :)

Comment: why the need for two different locators though? XPath or CSS can find both.